# Is there anything wrong with this SQL statement for Sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Just to give a background, I'm using Sphinx to do searches via PHP/MySQL. This is run through the system we have. Here is the SQL statement in question:

```
select * from [TABLE_NAME] where match('@keywords "homeschooling"') and status = 3 order by rand() limit 25
```

I'm getting this error with the said statement:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

However, if I use that exact statement and run it by itself, it does work! So I'm not sure what the problem is.

To recap, SQL statement does not work and returns an error when run via the system but it works when run by itself.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "run via the system" and "run by itself" ? Are you sure you're always connecting to Sphinx, not to mysql (mariadb) by using correct host, port etc.?

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen: By "run via the system", I meant the query was run in the context of the actual script (with all the other code for our system). "Run by itself" means I took out the said SQL statement and ran it without all the other code, in other words I ran just the SQL statement, either through PHP or through the MYSQL console. And yes, I'm 100% sure I'm connecting to sphinx.

Comment: A syntax error in sphinxql would be [an error like this](https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/blob/master/src/yysphinxql.c#L2630) rather than one that says 'corresponds to your MariaDB server version...`

Comment: @danblack: Hmmm I see. So are you suggesting I'm not really connected to Sphinx?

Comment: correct. The SQL you are executing is on the MariaDB server.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx, or [SphinxSE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-sphinxse/) , doesn't use the full text search syntax of MySQL.

After creating a Sphinx engine table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    id          BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    weight      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    query       VARCHAR(3072) NOT NULL,
    group_id    INTEGER,
    INDEX(query)
) ENGINE=SPHINX CONNECTION="sphinx://localhost:9312/test";
```

The query part of the string corresponds to the sphinx syntax for searching:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE query='test it;mode=any';
```

Comment: But the syntax I'm using is syntactically correct according to =.> http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html

Comment: Like [here : sphinxql](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql), this is connecting to sphinx directly using the mysql protocol and not run in MariaDB like your error indicates.

Comment: To furtehr clarify, You use SphinxQL syntax if connected DIRECTLY to a Sphinx (searchd) server. But use SphinxSE syntax, if connecting to a MySQL/MariaDB server, that has SphinxSE plugin installed (in this case the mysqld server connects to sphinx on your hehalf). Sphinx is good in that can use mysql joins btween the sphinx results virtual table, and the real database tables. SphinxQL is more powerful, but its a 'distinct' server to connect to.

Comment: @barryhunter: Thanks for the info! I'll do more research on this then get back to you guys.